# Delay a block of code

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, concurrency, task

In my WebApi project I have an endpoint that should delay a small block of code.
Let's make an example:

I need to implement a mechanism that permit the client to book for a resource. The booking time should only have a duration of 120 seconds and then expire.
In terms of code I have something like this:

```
//booking
foreach (var item in list) {
    item.Status = ItemStatus.Booked;
}
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

//Setup a delayed "thread" which removes the booking
Task.Delay( TimeSpan.FromMinutes( 2 ) )
    .ContinueWith( x => {
        //loop on the list and set the status to "ReadyForSale"
        //if this is still in the Booking
    } );

return;
```

I would like to understand if a solution like this satisfy my requirement. The current thread should not be blocked from the delayed task and I need to find a way to pass the list of items to the delayed task.

Comment: Try it and find out.  *You* tell *us* if this works for you.  If it *doesn't* work, then explain how it fails to do what you want it to do.

Comment: You're right and this is mainly a request for validation. What I am missing actually is how does it works behind-the-scene. Where does the delayed task lives? Does this way of working have any drawback in webapi? and things like this

Comment: Does it matter to you that if the application pool recycles (among many possible events) that this code won't run? If so, you might want to consider an alternative strategy (e.g. recording a `BookedDate` rather than purely a `Booked` status and then allowing new bookings if the `BookedDate` is more than 2 minutes in the past (there are issues with this approach too, especially as/when you wish to scale out onto multiple servers, but they can be dealt with))

Comment: @Lorenzo And yet you asked none of those things in your question.

Comment: in principal that works. What you should watch out for is that the Task.Delay continuation will run on another thread - and that the `list` might have been mutated in between - and must generally be designed in a thread-safe fashion.

Comment: @Matthias247 Right. I have reduced the code for simplicity but, yes, I know how to solve the mutating problem. Thanks

Comment: @Servy: I could say the same: and yet you did'nt give any contribution. I really do not understand people that spend time in criticizing, downvoting or things like that, instead of spending it to help. Anyway thanks for your findings.

Comment: @Lorenzo How does it make sense to ask the same thing of me?  I haven't posted a question to which I could fail to ask for what I wanted to know about.  How can you expect people to spend time helping you if you don't even ask for what you want to know?  Do you assume that everyone is able to read your mind to know what you want to ask, even though you asked something *completely* different?  If you don't ask an answerable question that actually asks what you want to know, you can't get people to tell you what you want to know.

Comment: @Servy: I think that stackoverflow is a democratic tool. If you dont want to answer nobody constrain you to do it. If you want to answer instead, your contribution can lead to editing the question, improving it and so on. We cannot say the same about controversies. No problem from my side.

Comment: You don't post answers to unanswerable questions to help the author edit the question into an answerable question.  That's not how the site works.  Comments are the place to point out the problems with a question so that the author can improve it when they post an unanswerable question that doesn't actually ask what they are interested in finding out.  Such "answers" would merit deletion, because they're not actually answers.

Comment: Yes but I dont continue with my controversy after the author said what I have written in my first comment. Please, if you dont want to help regarding the question, let others do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a risk that the task will never run. What if the sever crashes or IIS decides it needs to recycle the pool. 
There is the risk that the state would never be restored.
 I would probably set a `bokedAt` DateTime field in the database and then check if that time compared to now is more than two minutes to determine if the item is booked or not. Perhaps even a computed column that checks this and returns the state.

Comment: Thansk for your answer. However in case of implementing your solution, my continuation code should change, right? I mean, instead of trying to remove the booking from a specific item it should remove all the bookings that have expired. Also I do not need to setup a delayed task for every booking but maybe I only need a more generic one which runs periodically to remove all the expired bookings. Is this right?

Comment: No you need no task at all. When you query the table if bokedAt - Now > 2 min then the item is ReadyForSale again. No need to clear anything. When boked again just overwrite the bokedAt datetime with a new value.